# Incorrect "Sensitive data columns should be classified" report

Tags: azure-sql-database, vulnerability-assessment

Every week I'm getting a failed "Vulnerability Assessment" email report from my Microsoft Azure SQL Database that is incorrect.
It complains about columns that have **is_computed** column in sys.columns set to 1.
It is not possible to add a classification for those columns.

[image]

Is it possible to stop the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add those as a 'baseline', basically marking those items as ignorable items so that when the VA report runs again it ignores them.

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-vulnerability-assessment#4-set-your-baseline) for more information.

Comment: I have added those for all normal columns in the database. Took a bit of time, but not too much. The problem here is that the column is a calculated column, and you cannot add those to the baseline.

Comment: That's odd, I'm not seeing that behaviour at all. If I create a new Azure SQL DB, create a table with a column called "CreditCard" then run a VA scan, I get a warning about sensitive data column classification. If I then approve as baseline to eliminate that warning and run a new scan, that warning is not shown in the new scan.

Comment: to that table, please add a column called CopyOfCreditCard as a calculated column:  CopyOfCreditCard = (CreditCard)
and try to add 
ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION TO table.CopyOfCreditCard WITH (LABEL = 'Confidential', INFORMATION_TYPE = 'Financial')
Then you'll see that this is not possible. Next time you get a Vulnerability Assessment email from Microsoft, it will tell you to fix the new column. And this is not possible, as you can see.

Comment: Approving the list of warnings as a baseline solves the problem with the warning on calculated columns, just as you wrote in your answer. It is just annoying that I have to do that for each and every time I add a calculated column. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it will not fade away when we approve it as a baseline. Sometimes it does. But in most cases we will get baseline mismatch where we should go inside the database to classify those data that we approved as the baseline in the azure portal.
For more details on how to classify the data inside SQL please follow the below links.[Data discovery and classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-data-discovery-and-classification)
[RDBMS security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-data-discovery-and-classification?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=t-sql)